Can we use mybatis <foreach> in UPDATE statement with mysql
I'm trying to run multiple update statements in my Spring Boot application that is calling MySQL db using MyBatis. XML configured query looks like this:
<update id="updateAnglersTrackPositions" parameterType="java.util.List">
        <foreach collection="updateTrackPositionsList" item="item" separator=";">
            UPDATE angler
            SET trackNumber = #{item.trackPosition.trackNumber},
            sector = #{item.trackPosition.sector}
            WHERE id = #{item.anglerId}
        </foreach>;
    </update>

In AnlgerMapper I have:
int updateAnglersTrackPositions(@Param("updateTrackPositionsList") List<UpdateAnglersTrackPositionRequest> updateTrackPositionsRequest);
I expected multiple updates to happen but I am getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException
Here are the logs:
2024-04-22T11:49:15.542+02:00 ERROR 13496 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE angler
            SET trackNumber = 7,
            sector = 3
          ' at line 6
### The error may exist in com/example/FishingCompetitionManager/persistence/mapper/AnglerMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.example.FishingCompetitionManager.persistence.mapper.AnglerMapper.updateAnglersTrackPositions-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: UPDATE angler             SET trackNumber = ?,             sector = ?             WHERE id = ?          ;              UPDATE angler             SET trackNumber = ?,             sector = ?             WHERE id = ?          ;
### Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE angler
            SET trackNumber = 7,
            sector = 3
          ' at line 6
; bad SQL grammar []] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE angler
            SET trackNumber = 7,
            sector = 3
          ' at line 6
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.3.0.jar:8.3.0]

I don't have this error if I send one element in the list. For example this would work:
[
  {
    "anglerId": 310,
    "trackPosition": {
      "sector": 3,
      "trackNumber": 6
    }
  }
]

But If I put one more element it won't work. If I try this, I get the error mentioned aboe:
[
  {
    "anglerId": 310,
    "trackPosition": {
      "sector": 3,
      "trackNumber": 6
    }
  },
  {
    "anglerId": 311,
    "trackPosition": {
      "sector": 3,
      "trackNumber": 7
    }
  }
]

Versions used:
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mybatis:mybatis-spring:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:jar:8.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.mybatis:mybatis:jar:3.5.16:compile

What I have tried:

Adding open="(" close=")" in the foreach definition
Putting ";" after foreach closing tag. </foreach>;
Using BEGIN beofre foreach tag and END; after the foreach closing tag.

Does anyone have an idea how I can make this work? Is it even possible, is that a good practice to use foreach in update statement?

It may work if you add allowMultiQueries=true to the JDBC URL. Multi-queries has some disadvantages 1) you can't know which UPDATE failed, 2) you can't get update count of each UPDATE, 3) it's not efficient very much. In general, batch operation is recommended.

It's a known restriction for Mysql, documented here: https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1497.
To make it work, you need to add a query parameter allowMultiQueries=true to your connection URL - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?allowMultiQueries=true
And the update statement should look like this
<update id="updateAnglersTrackPositions" parameterType="java.util.List">
    <foreach collection="updateTrackPositionsList" item="item" separator=";">
            UPDATE angler
            SET trackNumber = #{item.trackPosition.trackNumber},
            sector = #{item.trackPosition.sector}
            WHERE id = #{item.anglerId}
    </foreach>
</update>

